# How should I increase the number of && operators as per the array argument is passed in function?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom-events, keyboard-events

```
function ShortCutKey(elemKey, keyCode, func) {
    var elemId = document.getElementById(elemKey);
    function RunFuncShorcut(enKey, numkeys) {
        if (numkeys > 1) {
            if (enKey.code == keyCode[0] && enKey.code == keyCode[1]) func();
        } else{
            if (enKey.code == keyCode[0]) func();
        }
    }
    if (Array.isArray(keyCode)){
        if (keyCode.length > 1) {
            elemKey.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
                RunFuncShorcut(keyCode, 2);
            });
        } else{
            elemKey.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
                RunFuncShorcut(keyCode, 1);
            });
        }
    }
    else{
        throw "2nd Argument must be an Array";
    } 
}
```

It is just limited to two keys means only a combination of two keys. I want multiple combination with less code... But I still don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
> test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```js
function ShortCutKey(elemKey, keyCodes, func) {
    const elemId = document.getElementById(elemKey);
    function RunFuncShorcut(enKey) {
        if (keyCodes.every(keyCode => keyCode === enKey.code)) func();
    }
    if (Array.isArray(keyCodes)){
        elemKey.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
            RunFuncShorcut(keyCodes);
        });
    }
    else{
        throw "2nd Argument must be an Array";
    } 
}
```

Comment: "I want to use it every time like
`ShortCutKey("SomeElem", ["Slash"], focus);` But it is not working as it is running when the webpage is loading. I used `console.log()` to check when it is called but it gets called without **keyup** function

Comment: @ShreyBhangale This seems like a different, completely unrelated problem. I answered _"How should I increase the number of && operators as per the array argument is passed in function?"_

Comment: Well... that it is not unrelated problem you see the....
When I keyup on certain element i will try any combination like
`ctrl`+`,` or 'ctrl'+`shift`+`,` or `ctrl`+`shift`+`alt`+`,` so the number of keycode are increasing that's why in `if` statement it will need _certainkey_ && _certainkey_ && _certainkey_ like this